# Issue with generics for extension function to Reactor Mono in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, project-reactor

I am trying to create a `DTO` interface which has a method to transform the dto back into its original model. Now I wanted to create an extension function to the `Mono` class to allow for better readability. But I cant get it to work, could somebody be so kind and help me out.

```
class StringDTO(private val s: String) : DTO<String> {
    override fun fromModel(model: String): DTO<String> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun toModel(): String {
        return s
    }
}

val s = Mono.just("asd")
    .map { StringDTO(it) }
    .toModel<String>()
    .block()

println("s = ${s}")

fun <T> Mono<DTO<T>>.toModel(): Mono<T> {
    return this.map(DTO<T>::toModel)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring the type parameter of `Mono` with `out` modifier in the extension function solves the issue:

```kotlin
fun <T> Mono<out DTO<T>>.toModel(): Mono<T> {
    return this.map(DTO<T>::toModel)
}
```